The date provided in the filter query must be within the last 30 days and not in the future
I have the following request which works fine when days is less than 30.
days = 29

end = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
start = end - timedelta(days=days)
query_parameters = CallRecordsRequestBuilder.CallRecordsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
    filter=" ".join(
        f"""
        participants_v2/any(p:p/id eq '{uuid}')
        and
        startDateTime ge {start.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}
        and
        startDateTime lt {end.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}
    """.split()
    )
)

When I try to fetch 30 days, I receive the following error

ODataError: APIError Code: 400 message: None error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='BadRequest', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={}, client_request_id='647fb989-75ef-4f39-8804-1a7c6da25cf1', date=DateTime(2024, 7, 5, 16, 14, 21, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), odata_type=None, request_id='13371966-0244-40c0-a503-dca6082d53dc'), message='The date provided in the filter query must be within the last 30 days and not in the future.', target=None)

So my question is, how to adjust the query, or how to make the query to cover an entire month given that some months have 31 days?

This doesn't look like a problem with your code. The API you're calling only allows you to go 30 days back, regardless of the length of the month.

Yes, but if you read the question, my problem raises when I put 30 days, which should work.

It sounds like they include the current day when counting. So if you subtract 30 days from now, that's actually 31 total days.

Interesting... Thank you
